# Adjust UINavigationBar height with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have to following code to adjust the height of my `UINavigationBar`:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 90)];
```

This works only for a split second when pushing the view before the bar resizes to its default height. I think this is because Auto Layout is enabled, but I'm not sure. How would I keep my `UINavigationBar` at my desired height without it returning to its default state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides some great sample code demonstrating common ways to manage the navigation bar in the [Customizing UINavigationBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/navbar/Introduction/Intro.html) project. That's probably the best place to find the specific setup for what you're trying to do.

To answer the specific question, you would need to create a custom subclass of UINavigationBar and override the height in `layoutSubviews` since ultimately, Apple's code will continually attempt to reset the size during transitions.

Comment: Apple's project is nice but it won't use AutoLayout to set the new content :(